# Font size in textfield libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I change the size of textfield font in libgdx?

```
UserNameTextField = new TextField("", GlobalSKin);
UserNameTextField. ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various builtin methods you can call to set size. 
If you just want to set the size of textfield you can call

```
UserNameTextField.setWidth(float width) Or UserNameTextField.setHeight(float width) or UserNameTextField.setMaxLength(maxLength)
```

And if you only want to set size of font then do it like `

```
TextField.TextFieldStyle textFieldStyle = skin.get(TextField.TextFieldStyle.class);
textFieldStyle.font.scale(1.6f);
```

`

You can check all methods , just need to take a look at API.

Comment: it seems that `textFieldStyle.font.scale` does not exist anymore. FYI