# Java - Libgdx : How to change textfield's font size?

Tags: fonts, libgdx, size, textfield

I was looking for how to change the font size of a textfield and I found this solution on stackoverflow:

```
TextField.TextFieldStyle textFieldStyle = skin.get(TextField.TextFieldStyle.class);
textFieldStyle.font.scale(1.6f);
```

The problem is I don't use the textfieldstyle, here is my code:

```
réponse = new TextField("", skin);
réponse.setPosition(stage.getWidth() / 2 - 445, stage.getHeight() / 1 - 1600);
réponse.setSize(900, 120);
stage.addActor(réponse);
réponse.setTextFieldListener(new TextField.TextFieldListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char c) {
        if(réponse.getText().equals("")){
            réponse.setText("");
        } else if(réponse.getText().equals("riviere")){
            game.setScreen(new Stage1(game));
            music.stop();
        }
        else if(!réponse.getText().equals("riviere")){
            ecrireLeTexte = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Maybe a solution with getStyle() ?

Comment: I've found the answer to your question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185704/font-size-in-textfield-libgdx .

Comment: Yes that's what I found, I told it up there, but it doesn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you posted and the code you have now are almost the same.

You are creating a `TextField` using a `Skin`. You can also create a `TextField` using a `TextFieldStyle`. Instead of creating a brand new `TextFieldStyle` you can do as shown, and get the existing one from your `Skin`.

Your code would then look like:

```
TextField.TextFieldStyle textFieldStyle = skin.get(TextField.TextFieldStyle.class);
textFieldStyle.font.scale(1.6f);

réponse = new TextField("", textFieldStyle);
```

This is almost exactly what is happening behind the scenes when you create a `TextField` using `Skin`. Here is the constructor of `TextField(String, Skin)` from libGDX's code:

```
public TextField (String text, Skin skin) {
    this(text, skin.get(TextFieldStyle.class));
}
```

You can see that it is essentially doing:

```
TextButtonStyle style = skin.get(TextFieldStyle.class);
textField = new TextField(text, style);
```

And that is the same thing as your new code.

Comment: textFieldStyle.font.scale(); is not working, it can't solve method .scale()

Comment: In my experience, you can't really change the sizes of fonts once they've been loaded. Why don't you just make the font size bigger to begin with?